# javascript time counter from today to prior date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fix my time counter from now to prior date,but when I execute it. it says 5 hours , when it should be 90 days 00 minutes : 00 seconds and 00 milliseconds. So I am trying to fix it, but I am suck at it

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 28, 2019 08:10:34").getTime();
var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);  
console.log(days);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  if (distance < 0) {
  clearInterval(countdownfunction);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You have the prior date setup as TODAY and your NOW date is obviously TODAY. So there is only a 5 hour difference.

Comment: From where 90days comes ? You compare now to 28-2-2019

Comment: I did that, but it seems always return me to 5 hours

Comment: I run your code in a local testing environ, works fine. I did change the countDownDate to a date three months from now, to test. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/a91bhvsm/1/

Comment: What is today's date, @cyb3rpunk? 28-2-2019. Thus, depending on your timezone, you are saying "8:10:34 AM Today"

Comment: Maybe you have some server-side code generating that date value in your javascript, and it's picking a date 5 hours away.